# VS CODE: Unable to import - pylint(import:error)

Tags: django, visual-studio-code

I have a django project. In views.py file, I tried to import my models (or anything from MYAPP) like this:

```
from MYAPP.models import *
from MYAPP.api.user.serializers import *
```

It shows me a warning "Unable to import 'MYAPP.~~'".
My project is still running normally but VS-Code reported many errors so I don't know if it is true or not.

How can I fix it? Thank you ^^.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your project is running normally with views,the problem is with the extension,not with your code.disable them and try again.

Comment: It's work when I disable Python Extension from Microsoft ~~

Comment: disable python estension?i mean,what?

Comment: I mean, linting and debugging